# Version Control by Making different folder

Tags: php, version-control

I'm working from a remote site. In the jungle to be precise. My way of version control is for every upgrade, I will copy the whole current file to a new folder and name it based on the version and upgrade code on the main folder.
Is this right?

Comment: Why not use an actual version control system like git or mercurial or even svn?

Comment: Minimially, you won't have notes, version numbers, and if that server goes down you lose all versions.

Comment: what you describe sounds like a pseudo deployment process - but it is not version control.

Answer (score 2):

No. This is not a professional way of working with version control. You should use GIT, SVN o something similar. Your approach is only creating redundancies on your local machines and wont help you identify any changes made in different versions. GIT stores differences and therefore is helpful in keeping check of what exactly changed between two versions and is therefore actually helpful in debugging.

Comment: Is there an offline way to do this?

Comment: Yes, git and more options are all available offline. You will need the internet to learn about them, though. :P

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

Your approach will give you some kind of backup, but not professional version control. The difference is that your process is a lot more manual and does not document any changes you made. You cannot see when you made changes, or why.

Version control systems like git are vastly superior to that.

For most version control systems in general it doesn't matter where you are, or where your team is, as long as you have network in between.

A good approach would be to read up on git either on [the official git-scm website](https://git-scm.com/), or maybe over at [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/). Those should get you started on how basic use works. If you want a bit more explanation of how its magic works, I suggest [the excellent talk *Git for ages 4 and up*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3m7BgIvC-uQ) by [Schwern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14660/schwern).

Because *deployment* has been menitoned also, I would like to add that how you deal with your finished product doesn't really matter to version control. But the version control software can be used by deployment systems to get the newest version, which is convenient.